# Ignore subdirectories in pathlilb object

Tags: python, pathlib

Is it possible to not go into sub directories when creating a pathlib generator?

I have a file structure like this:

```
-dataset/
    - file1.hea
    - file2.hea
    - file3.hea
    - file4.hea
    - subfolder/
         - xfile1.hea
         - xfile2.hea
```

I want to iterate through the files in the dataset folder and not subfolders.
the code now:

```
import pathlib
path = 'dataset'
files = pathlib.Path(path).rglob('*.hea')
for file in files:
    print(file.name)
```

This gives the result:

```
file1.hea
file2.hea
file3.hea
file4.hea
xfile1.hea
xfile2.hea
```

but the result I want is:

```
file1.hea
file2.hea
file3.hea
file4.hea
```

Is this possible without checking the name every iteration?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I'm reading the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) here right, it says that `.rglob()` is the exact same as `.glob()` except `.rglob()` adds a `**/` at the front, meaning `.rglob()` will look through subdirectories.

So, just use `.glob()`